# How to set the text absolutely (CSS) in the middle of a div despite a changing width div behind him?

Tags: html, css

The image shows what I want to accomplish:

[image: What I want to make]

Here is the code that I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZNtKj/202/

```
<div style="width: 200px" >
 <div class="niveles-porcentaje">
     <div class="alta" style="width: 40%"> <span class="porcentaje">40%</span></div>
 </div>
```

And the style I am having trouble to fix:

```
div.niveles-porcentaje {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    align-self:center;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-table;
    background-color:#D7D7D7;

}
div.alta {
    display:inline-table; /*inside a table*/
    line-height: 2em;
    background-color: #06AC09;
    height:100%;
    float:left;

}
 span.porcentaje{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    z-index:99;
}
```

The div will be inside a td.

Comment: You want 4 progress bar or change the color according percent?

Comment: @AlexandreVicenzi He wants the text to center in the full bar; right now it's centering in the filled progress section.

Comment: @hugomosh PS Z-index doesn't do anything unless you also apply `position`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make the text's parent full width. To do that, remove the back color and `width` definition from the `.alta` div, and create an inner absolute div to deal with the color fill, that won't interfeer with the text.

Also, remember to set the text `span` to `display: block` to be full width. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZNtKj/209/

```
 <div style="width: 200px" >
     <div class="niveles-porcentaje">
         <div class="alta">
             <div class="fill" style="width: 40%"></div>
             <span class="porcentaje">40%</span>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.niveles-porcentaje {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    align-self:center;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-table;
    background-color:#D7D7D7;

}
div.alta {
    display:inline-table; /*inside a table*/
    line-height: 2em;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative; 
}

div.alta .fill {
    background-color: #06AC09;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
}
 span.porcentaje{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    z-index:99;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNtKj/210/) with example. You can simply change the text div width to see the result.

```
    div.niveles-porcentaje {
        width:100%;
        height:20px;
        align-self:center;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#D7D7D7;
    position:relative;

    }
    div.alta {
        line-height: 2em;
        background-color: #06AC09;
        height:20px;
        float:left;
        position:relative;    

    }
     span.porcentaje{
         position:absolute;
         left:46%;
         top:0;
    }
```